# Need understanding for public and private

Tags: java, private, public

I have pasted the code, now my query is that in 1st class named "accesssp" I have added object and then written SOP then why cant I have output as value of B ?? b's access is private but I am fetching value in same class

I've done section BOLD which I don't understand.

```
class accesssp  {

public int a=56;
private int b=5566;
public int c=58766;

System.out.println(b);

}

class accesssp1 extends accesssp{

public void accessd()   {

    System.out.println(a);
    System.out.println(c);

}

}
public class Access_Spf {

public static void main(String[] args) {


    accesssp1 sp1 = new accesssp1();
    sp1.accessd();
}

}
```

Comment: The code doesn't compile. You should READ the compiler error message. And if you don't understand it, you should paste the exact and complete compiler error message, instead of letting us guess what the problem might be.

Comment: You need to put the print statement in a method of the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`System.out.println(b);` is neither in the `main()` method nor in any function. This cannot be executed directly as you have done. On a side note, variable `b` will not be accessible in `accesssp1` class.

Comment: then what is method to show value of b,
Sorrrry bt I am a beginner, so please dont laugh at me... :D

Comment: use any method. try: `public accesssp() { System.out.println(b);}`

Comment: here it is being called inside the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Well, Its cuz system.out.println statement should be inside a method/constructor body, as you have done in your 2nd and 3rd cases. and this is a compiler error.

```
class accesssp  {

public int a=56;
private int b=5566;
public int c=58766;

System.out.println(b);//should be inside a method/cons body

}
```

Comment: I understood what you wanted to say bt not properly,
Would you please tell me, in code where should I put it ??

Comment: your print statement can't be inside a class body. it has to inside a block or method body.

Answer (score 0):

SOP should be inside any method. Use a constructor and print it inside the constructor and then call super() in the constructor of **accesssp1**

```
class accesssp  {

public int a=56;
private int b=5566;
public int c=58766;

public accesssp()

{
System.out.println(b);
}

}

class accesssp1 extends accesssp{

public accesssp1()
{
super();
}


public void accessd()   {


System.out.println(a);
System.out.println(c);

}

}
public class Access_Spf {

public static void main(String[] args) {


accesssp1 sp1 = new accesssp1();
sp1.accessd();

}

}
```

Comment: thank you so much sir,
hoping for further help from you.
Thanks again... :)

Comment: You are welcome. You may accept this. You could have googled this. Many will down vote this question.

Comment: I dont care about this voting system. coz I am a beginner in java.
By the way,
Need answer of a stupid question,
What is need of constructer ??

Comment: constructor is not necessary. You can use any method. But executable statements must be inside of any method. Otherwise it will show error.

Comment: And you should care about the voting. If u ask simple questions they will down vote you and you will be permanently banned from asking questions here.

Answer (score 0):

There are access specifiers in java, there are,

```
private, public and protected.
```

Each of above has there on features,they are explained on the basis of there scope and visibility.

```
private has scope & visibility resides only on inside a function or there the class.
```

eg.:

```
public class classFirst
{
    private int variableName1;//scope and visibility inside this class
    public void function1()
    {
       private int variableName2;//scope and visibility inside this function not use outside.
    }
}
```

public has scope & visibility resides anywhere on the project(when that can calls outside only calls with their objects.). This values are accessed with their objects.

eg.:

```
public class classSecond
{
    public int variableName1;//scope and visibility anywhere on the project
    public void function1()
    {
       public int variableName2;//scope and visibility anywhere on the project
    }
}
```

protected has scope & visibility is on inside of class and also accessed public inherited classes.

So `System.out.println(b);` statement must be inside a constructor of first class.

Comment: I would give a +1 if there weren't access specifiers inside methods, they give compile errors.